# Should we have thousands of sleeping database connections from the Crawler server?

Tags: crawling, sql-server

Our IT Manager has brought up a situation where it looks like we have about 5000+ sleeping connections from the Crawl Server to our SQL Server.  This seems like quite a bit and it's been slowly creeping up since our database server reboot a few weeks ago, after the machine was patched.  So even if we reboot it looks like the connections will come back.

We are running SharePoint 2010 with the Search Service installed, the connections are all coming from the Crawler Server (we split up our Search Service to a few machines to separate the Crawler and Query services).

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've never been able to get a straight answer on this I am going to close this with - No Answer.

If anyone ever finds out why the connections that are supposed to be reused, are not, please let me know.  Otherwise I don't want to leave this open.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed any third party solutions or custom solutions? If so you might not dispose of your SharePoint objects correctly. Each SPRequest-object (SPSite, etc.) creates its own data base connection. Try checking your ULS-Logs for any warnings about "undisposed requests".

Comment: The connections are all coming from the server that is used only for Crawling the site, there is nothing else there that would make a connection.

Comment: well, you're right - nothing else makes a connection. But the crawler itself creates connections to the content, i.e. all content. Therefore SPRequest objects still get created.

Comment: Ok, that I get.  Should it generate that many without releasing them?  Unless the Crawler is buggy I would expect it to release, or at the least reuse, those resources.

Comment: Well, it should not, but with mistakes in programming, these resources might not be released. The problem does not reside on the crawler side, but on the SharePoint application side. For a in depth explanation, have a look at following article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/12/05/disposing-spweb-and-spsite-objects.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that but since this is the Search Service code how do I go about adjusting it?  I've never seen anything that has shown how to make those changes.

Comment: It's not the Search Service code. The search service acts just like a heavy user who is polling all content pages.

Comment: That I understand, but is there a rationale for why it just generates connections and never reuses them?  I'm just trying to understand if this is normal.

Comment: The problem is, that the connections are supposed to be reused. This way the data base can be accessed more quickly. However, due to the concepts of the SharePoint architecture, these connections have to be closed explicitly by disposing of SharePoint objects that are no longer needed. Failing in doing so can result in your described phenomena. Are there any third party tools in your SharePoint environment?

Comment: No third party tools, read my first answer on this.  The connections ARE all from the Crawler and they are NEVER reused, this is why we end up in this situation.  It's frustrating and I am trying to get a handle on this, even Microsoft has not had an answer for us on the issue.